# Semantic-ui themes not changing after gulp build

Tags: css, npm, gulp, semantic-ui

I have tried to change the semantic-ui theme in the theme.config file but nothing happens.. No errors on gulp or anything..

i have deleted the semantic.min.css file and build it again and no matter what theme i change to nothing happens.

example of the theme.config file:

```
/* Elements */
@button     : 'Amazon';
@container  : 'material';
@divider    : 'material';
@flag       : 'material';
@header     : 'material';
@icon       : 'material';
@image      : 'material';
@input      : 'material';
@label      : 'material';
@list       : 'material';
@loader     : 'material';
@rail       : 'material';
@reveal     : 'material';
@segment    : 'material';
@step       : 'material';
```

Do anybody know what i might be doing wrong?

I have also tried to reinstall semantic and also on a different project.. Cant figure out why i wouldnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work.

Just leaving a answer for the people who might be having the same trouble.

I believe the problem was the version of Node, that was causing the trouble. Even though no errors was displayed, updating to the lastest stable version seems to have solved it for me.

Comment: Worked for me with Node v8.1.2

Answer (score 0):

after change your `theme.config` please re-build your gulp by using `gulp build` command and then try reload your browser to check it again.

it will work.

Comment: Nope, thats the problem. As i said, i also completely deleted the file and tried again. A new file is generated with gulp build but its the exact same content as before